# Integrate Google OAuth and Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito, google-authentication

I want to allow users to login via Google to my app with Cognito. It seems I can allow Google **Plus** users to login but I actually want Google users (NOT necessarily Google Plus users) to login. As an extension, for the current project, I actually want users in my organization (`*@myorg.com`) to login.

I read https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-federated-single-sign-on-to-aws-using-google-apps/, but I am more familiar with OAuth/OpenID and prefer to use that. How can I configure that?

So far I tried IAM > Congigure provider but dont know what to fill:

[image]

Where do I find provider URL and Audience.

---

I am not familiar with SAML, isit more approperiate for my usecase? When do I use it over OAuth/OpenID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect

didn't tried it, but I think you need to use "https://accounts.google.com"
as that is where the ".well-known/openid-configuration" is

Comment: I'm using the suggested `https://accounts.google.com` and getting an error saying the URL is invalid.

Comment: Wow, looks like the "/" at the end of this is required. So make sure you are using `https://accounts.google.com/`